# What is the maximum amount of Connected App created in one Organization?

Tags: connected-apps

What is the maximum amount of Connected App created in one Organization?

I am considering several implementation options to provide end user options to switch between orgs within the managed package.

One of the viable option is to dynamically register a connected app per each subscriber.

My assumption was that the connected app will be created in a subscriber org, however, this is not true, the connected app is created in the org where the source connected app initial access token is from. This means, the number of connected app in a single org will increase with an influx of the potential customers, which may sooner or later hit a limit.

So I need to know if there is any limit on number of Connected Apps per organization and what is it?

Currently I have created 100 connected apps and have just created 101st.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The official doc has the following note](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oidc_dynamic_client_reg_flow.htm&type=5)

> NOTE The maximum number of OAuth 2.0 connected apps that can be
> registered through the dynamic client registration endpoint is 100.

When I tried to execute dynamic app registration in the loop, I have finally found this hard limit experimentally:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Api.register();
}
```

The failure happens on the 101st connected app registration try.

The following error occurs if you try to execute more than 100 dynamic app registration

```
System.UnexpectedException: Bad Request400{"error":"exceeded_registration_limit","error_description":"client registration has exceeded the limit for the organization"}
```

While actually after that you may create another connected app manually.

Looks like there are different limits on connected apps created manually and created within dynamic app registration.

---

So when we query

```
Select Count() From ConnectedApplication
```

the result may exceed 100, however, this doesn't mean that we have created more than 100 ConnectedApps still it counts both the connected apps, created by dynamic app registrations, connected apps, created manually and installed connected apps.

---

The exception thrown is not possible to catch.

---

Update: Salesforce Support specialist confirmed that dynamic app registration limit can be raised up to 3000.

Still, there is no limit on the number of created connected app manually or using Metadata API (I was able to create 51650 connected app records in a single org after that I wasn't able to delete any of these connected apps due to the performance issue in the org, so this is not recommended to have high amount of connected apps in a single org)

Comment: 100 is the limit documented for [dynamic client registrations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oidc_dynamic_client_reg_flow.htm&type=5). If this limit applies to more than just dynamic clients, it should be either a documentation bug or a limit enforcement bug. Thanks for doing the experiment and documenting the results!

Comment: thanks for the comment, I missed that note in the documentation